# What is the best-practice for managing Aegir sites in Git?

Tags: 7, version-control, aegir

I know there is a million ways this could be done, I'm more looking for the "best-practice" of how this "should" be done.

I have an Aegir setup with 4 different Drupal platforms.
Within each platform there are several Sites.
There is also modules/themes in the "all" directory that are shard between the sites.

How would one one manage these platforms/sites in Git?

Should we create 1 repo for the entire "platforms" folder?
A repo for each platform folder?
A repo for each platform folder and a repo for each site?
A repo for each site and a repo for each "all" site?

What would be the best practice for this?

thanks!

Comment: I think it boils down to what is best/easiest for you and your team considering workflow, deployment methods, etc.

Comment: I agree with @enzipher: What is best depends from you, and the workflow used from you, or your team. This makes the question subjective, and not constructive. For every user suggesting to use a method there is at least one use suggesting to use a different method, or exactly the opposite.

Comment: oh! what I was looking for wasn't a subjective answer, I was looking more for a this is a "by the book" answer. that's what a best practice is, it's not subjective, it's by the book.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the recommended way for Barracuda/Aegir by Omega8:

> The recommended (and also more advanced) way to manage your Sites code
>   is to use Makefiles (and then Drush Make) to build your Platforms,
>   apply patches to contrib or custom modules etc, then using Profiler
>   module to create your custom Installation Profile and manage in your
>   Git repo just your Makefiles, your Installation Profiles and only your
>   custom modules and patches – in a separate repo per module and per
>   theme.

Source: http://omega8.cc/managing-your-code-in-the-aegir-style-110.